# React + Electron + Typescript - Pass defaultValue prop to JSX Input Element using data fetched asynchronously (Promise)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron

I have what is meant to be a settings menu component, and I am attempting to read from a JSON file located in the app data directory. For this persistent data storage, I'm using `electron-store@^8.0.0`. I have a `bridge.ts` file and I am using `contextBridge` to expose methods to the renderers. The method to fetch data is as follows:

`bridge.ts`

```js
export const api = {
  . . .

  getSetting: async (setting: string) => {
    ipcRenderer.send('get-setting', setting)

    let response

    async function awaitResponse() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ipcRenderer.once('get-setting-reply', (event, data) => {
          resolve(data)
        })
      })
    }

    response = await awaitResponse()

    return response
  },

  . . .
}
```

And the implementation in `main.ts`:

`main.ts`

```js
async function registerListeners () {
  . . .

  ipcMain.on('get-setting', (event, args) => {
    event.reply( 'get-setting-reply', storage.get(args.setting) )
  })

  . . .
}
```

Now, back to the settings component. With the data that I have fetched, I attempt to set the `defaultValue` prop of the `<input>` element, but to no avail. Typescript tells me that:

```
Type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.
```

`Settings/index.tsx`

```js
            <Setting>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    spellCheck="false"
                    onChange={ (e) => window.Main.setSetting("username", e.target.value) }
                    defaultValue={ window.Main.getSetting('username') }
                />
            </Setting>
```

Full error:

```
Type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.
 
Type 'Promise<unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly string[]': length, concat, join, slice, and 16 more.ts(2322)

index.d.ts(1818, 9): The expected type comes from property 'defaultValue' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'
```

I'm not aware of a way to extract the value from a promise, even after 8 hours of searching. With the `.then` approach, for example, a new promise is returned!

Finally, for some reason, it still seems to display it inside the `<input>` without throwing an error. No clue why this happens.

Is there maybe another way, that does not return a promise object?

Thank you! <3